# How to refer OLD record in trigger when statement is INSERT ON CONFLICT DO UPDATE?

Tags: postgresql

I am writing a trigger like this,

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION insert_check()
RETURNS TRIGGER AS $$
BEGIN
    IF NEW.id = '' OR NEW.name = '' THEN
        RAISE EXCEPTION 'id or name cannot be empty string';
    END IF;
    NEW._mtime = now();      -- update mtime
    NEW._counter = COALESCE(OLD._counter, 0) + 1;    -- update a counter
    RETURN NEW;
END
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;

CREATE TRIGGER insert_check BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE on topic
FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE PROCEDURE insert_check();
```

But if the statement is `INSERT ON CONFLICT DO UPDATE ...`, I couldn't refer OLD in the trigger function.

I know I can modify _counter in that statement itself, but I want to seperate busniess and audit logics.

So what should I do?

Comment: Did you try to use `TG_OP` [special variable](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/plpgsql-trigger.html)?

Comment: @Abelisto, Ok you are right. Statement `INSERT ON CONFLICT DO ...` will trigger two event in trigger, the first is INSERT and the second is UPDATE. And then I can refer OLD when TG_OP = 'UPDATE'. Thank you very much!